# npx create-react-app ./ isn't creating a .git file

Tags: reactjs, git

Whenever I try to create a new react app it unfortunately doesn't create a .git file as it should in the image provided

https://i.stack.imgur.com/SWkhX.png

Comment: Do you mean `.git` **folder**? There is no `.git` file

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio Code hides the `.git` folder by default. To show it:

1. Go to settings and search 'files exclude'.
2. In the `Files: Exclude` settings remove `**/.git`
   [image: Exclude Git]